# Xml to HTML5 with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I thought this was a quite common question, but for some reason I can't find the answer anywhere.

I want to read out xml data and put it in my html5 app. The xml file is hosted on a different server. So I've allready got an HTML5 site with layout, I've got the location of my xml file, how do I implement specific data in to my html?

Answer (score 2):

In most browsers, you can't [for security reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). In some newer browsers you can use [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) providing the data provider cooperates.

Otherwise you need to make the data available on the same server as the application, or have the data provided in [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) format.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you cannot use Javascript to read content from a different domain.

You need to write a server-side script on your domain to forward the XML.
You can then use normal AJAX to create the page.